# Ошибка Unity3d. Как исправить?

Tags: unity3d

Выдаёт на консоли:

```
Screen position out of view frustum (screen pos 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.300000) (Camera rect 0 0 0 0)
UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI()
```

Comment: Это у вас при загрузке юнити? Версия наверное 5.2?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский верно, версия 5.2.1

Comment: вроде у нее небольшие баги. Данная ошибка ни на что не влияет по крупному. Если очистить консоль она не будет всплывать. А лучше хотя бы до 5.3 обновиться. Там всё ок.......или патч ставить.... но лучше новую версию)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да, это я уже понял по нескольким проектам - думал, что с камерой что-то намудрил сам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как и было отмечено в комментариях, данная ошибка связана с внутренними Unity-причинами. Ее можно игнорировать или обновить версию редактора на более новую.

Comment: Она тянется с 2008 года (судя по упоминаниями на форуме юнити) и по сих пор в Unity 2018b10 она также появляется